# Javascript drag and drop: изображение при перетягивании

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Доброе время суток, во время перетаскивания какого-либо объекта при помощи встроенной функции draggable='true' мы тянем его представление, изображение этого объекта. Возможно ли как-то изменить это изображение, заменить на представление другого блока?

Answer (score 0):

[Код](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html) по сабжу нашёл, вопрос решён.

```
<div id="drag-with-image" class="dragdemo" draggable="true">drag me</div>

document.getElementById("drag-with-image").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://kryogenix.org/images/hackergotchi-simpler.png";
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

Comment: приложите код в ответ, другим тоже может пригодиться)

Comment: почитайте правила ресурса - ссылка на ответ, не является ответом. Ссылка может устареть/сломаться/поменяться. И добавьте код в ответ, а не в комментарий, где его не удобно читать

Comment: @ThisMan, буду знать, спасибо